# Method for passing JS variable to PHP with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter application plugged into a wordpress site.  I need to modify a shortcode in php according to an html selected option value in my view. The shortcode adds a form to my html page. I am thinking that I need to use Ajax to move the data from JS to PHP. I am confused as to how to get this done. This is the basic sequence that must be done (minus the Ajax or whatever other method is needed):

In my View I need to have the following components:

```
<html>
    <select id="select-service">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

//This is where I am putting the short code I made in JS
<?php echo do_shortcode("shortCode GOES HERE"); ?>

</html>
<script>
    function getService() {
        var serviceItem = $('#select-service option:selected').text();
        shortCode = "[wpi_checkout item='" + serviceItem + "']" ;
        //AN AJAX SEQUENCE HERE?
        var postUrl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/ajax_serviceitem'; 
        $.ajax({
            url: postUrl,
            method: 'post',
            data: shortCode,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(getService);
    $('select').on('change', getService);
</script>
```

In my controller I suppose I need a function like this:

```
public function ajax_serviceitem() {
    $shortcode = $_POST('shortCode')
    $this->load->view('myview', $shortcode);
    //I am lost as to what to do next 
}
```

Am I on the right track or am I over complicating this?

Comment: Did you try it? - You likely want `shortCode = {"shortCode":serviceItem};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that although the php work is done on the server the variable passed back is in JS so it will not work.  I solved my problem by adding some php to my view to collect options from the view and build short codes from them:

```
//First: In css I hid all the elements that the short code produces


//This select box is built by a foreach routine in my controller.
<html>
    <select id="select-service">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

//This is where I am putting the short code.  I am grabbing $service['id'] from my database in my controller and sending it to the view. I am building a bunch of divs that reflect the values of the select options here rather than in the controller.  I have to do this because the wordpress do_shortcode() hook will only work in the view.
<?php foreach($available_services as $service) { 
    $shortcode = "[wpi_checkout item='" . $service['id'] "' title ='session_ID' callback_function='ea_paypalcallback']"; ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $service['id'] ?>" class="shortcode"><?php echo do_shortcode($shortcode)?></div>
<?php } ?>  

</html>
```

Then I ran the following on success from my Ajax send for other stuff:

```
var selServiceId = $('#select-service').val();
$('#' + selServiceId ).find(':submit').click();
```

That did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getService() {
        var serviceItem = $('#select-service option:selected').val();
        data = {'shortCode':serviceItem};
        //AN AJAX SEQUENCE HERE?
        var postUrl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/ajax_serviceitem'; 
        $.ajax({
            url: postUrl,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data : data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

======================== AND Another fix I seen is ==================

```
public function ajax_serviceitem() {
    $shortcode = $_POST['shortCode']
    $this->load->view('myview', $shortcode);
    //I am lost as to what to do next 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

**JS  :**

```
function getService() {
    var serviceItem = $('#select-service option:selected').val();
    data = {'shortCode':serviceItem};
    //AN AJAX SEQUENCE HERE?
    var postUrl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/ajax_serviceitem'; 
    $.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data : data,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'success') {
                console.log("Success Request");
                $("#view_selector").html(response.my_view_file);
            } else {
                console.log("Fail Request");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP :**

```
public function ajax_serviceitem() {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $shortcode =  $this->input->post('shortCode');
        if (!empty($shortcode)) {
            $my_view_file = $this->load->view('myview', $shortcode, TRUE);
            $data['status'] = 'success';
            $data['my_view_file'] = $my_view_file;
        } else {
            $data['status'] = 'error';
            $data['my_view_file'] = "";
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    } else {
        redirect('login/logout'); // Logout URL here
    }
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: NikuNj--thanks, I am trying this out and I get no errors however I am having difficulty pulling the shortcode back in at `<?php echo do_shortcode("shortCode GOES HERE"); ?>`  .  I am not sure how to pull it back in.  I have tried `<?php echo do_shortcode(json_encode($shortcode)); ?>` and that does not work.  That is I am returned Null.

Comment: @craig I am not understand do_short_code function so please explain more.

Comment: Thanks.  The `do_shortcode()` function is used in Wordpress to run a Wordpress shortcode in a page other than a wordpress page such as in a plugin.  The shortcode has a format such as `[wpi_checkout item='Volvo']`  I am building the short code in JS and sending it to PHP to be used within the `do_shortcode()` function. So, I need to send back the shortcode in the $shortcode variable such as `do_shortcode('$shortcode')`.